# How to call another function from the function that is passed to evaluate in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, scope, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('mysite.html', function() {
});

/* Casper configuration */

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
})

function getAllImages()
{
    // Get all images
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
    evaluateImages(images);
}

function evaluateImages(images)
{
    console.log("I am in evaluateImages");
}

// Then find all pictures
casper.then(function() {
    var product_image = this.evaluate(getAllImages);
});

casper.run();
```

But it never gets to evaluteImages function. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have never used CasperJS, however from what i've read in the docs, I believe that it's because the `evaluateImages` function doesn't exist in the page's context.

I am not sure what's the best practice here, however it seems that you can return primitives from evaluate callbacks, so you could technically do something like:

```
function getAllImages() {
    // Get all images
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    //Return an array that contains all images src attribute
    return Array.prototype.map.call(images, function (img) {
        return img.src;
    });
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var images = this.evaluate(getAllImages);

evaluateImages(images);
```

**EDIT:**

> I need to treat all the images in the page context, as I am comparing
>   each of them with other elements that are in the page...

Perhaps you could define a module in the page's context first:

```
this.evaluate(function () {
    window.yourNS = {
        evaluateImages: function (images) {
            //do something with images
        },
        getAllImages: function () {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can do something like:

```
this.evaluate(function () {
    yourNS.evaluateImages(yourNS.getAllImages());
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is right, so how can I use more than one function in the page's context? I need to do quite a lot of calculations within the page context, and I prefer not to have a huge function, but having several functions. Shall I put the "support" functions inside the one I am passing to the page context?

Comment: @HommerSmith I updated the answer, however I am not sure that's the best practice with CasperJS.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yeah, I have done that already, returning the srcs attributes, but that doesn't help. I need to treat all the images in the page context, as I am comparing each of them with other elements that are in the page...

Comment: Really clever. I will try this once I get home. Thanks